# Halo Reach: Can I play on a party without XBox Gold account

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-network, halo-reach

I have been recently added to a clan, and there are custom games played within the clan. I currently have XBox live gold account. Can I still play these custom matches without the gold account? If so what will be the drawbacks? I am planning to end my gold subscription. Hence the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can.

If you want to play online, however, you need to play splitscreen and the other player on your console (there is a max of 2 players per console when playing online) has to have Gold account. You will play as a Guest (not with your account).

If you want to play offline it's ok to create up to four splitscreen matches.

**Summary**: Someone in your console must have the Gold Account to play online. But doesn't have to be you. Of course, without your account you won't be in the clan unless the friend in your house is.

Comment: Maybe 4 player online. (2 player split co-op)

Answer (score 0):

To play on Xbox Live, either with friends or randoms, you will need a Gold account. You can however play LAN, or split-screen without a Gold Account.

Or, if one of your friends has a Gold account, you can split screen with them, and play as a Guest.

Answer (score -1):

You will need an Xbox Live Gold account to play matches online with other players.